# How could I add 1 to each input

Tags: python, python-3.x

Currently very new to python. I am taking a class on it at the moment. I am having trouble with my while and for loops and how to use them. I need to create a program that asks the user for a budget, then asks for amount spent for days up to 31. If the budget comes back negative I need to have the program restart.

```
    budget = float(input("What is your budget: "))
day = 0
while (budget < -1):
    budget = float(input("Please enter a positive budget: "))
```

I have no idea what I am doing.

Comment: What does your question have to do with adding 1 to the input?

Comment: `while (budget <= 0):`...

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. It would help to write your question more clearly. Do you mean you need to prompt the user for the budget for day 1, day 2, day 3, day 4, and so on until day 31?

Answer (score 0):

Let's step through your problems.

First, you mentioned that you may need your program to restart.
There are two ways we can do this.

1. Stick the entire thing in a while loop, have it repeat until the budget after a month is positive.
2. Stick the entire thing in a function, call that function again if the budget is negative.

I'd personally prefer the second one, but as you're working with while loops we can do the first one.

So, if you have the code that computes the budget for a month called `<stuff>`, you'll want to write something like this:

```
budget_is_negative = True
while budget_is_negative:
   <stuff>
   if budget_at_end_of_month >= 0:
       budget_is_negative = False
```

Here, I'm assuming you set some variable `budget_at_end_of_month` (likely some float) while executing `<stuff>`.

Now, let's think about how to write `<stuff>`.  We want it to:

1. Ask for a budget for the month.
2. Ask each day how much the user spent, but only for 31 days.

The first part is easy:

```
monthly_budget = float(nput("What is your budget: "))
```

Now, we want to incorporate a while loop to find how much we spend each day.
To do this, we'll want to introduce something called a *counter*, or a variable that keeps track of what day we're on.

```
day = 0
while day < 31:
    money_spent_today = float(input("How much did you spend today?: "))
```

Here, this will keep checking what day it is, always see that `0 < 31`  is true (as we never change the day), and thus enter an infinite loop.  Instead, what we want is to do the following

```
day = 0
while day < 31:
    money_spent_today = float(input("How much did you spend today?: "))
    day = day + 1
```

This will increment the day after you find out how much they spent each day.  We can write this more concisely as `day += 1`, but the first way is usually easier for beginners to understand.

Now, there's still some more work you'll need to do.  Namely:

1. Each day you ask how much they spent, and store it as `money_spent_today`.  The next day you'll overwrite this variable though.  How can you keep track of the total spent?
2. I've mentioned how to do a lot of the individual parts of this code.  You'll need to figure out how to put it all together.